# how to resize the size of div on button click if its in percentage Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to resize the div height on button click such that on each click its size reduce 1% in height.

I have this code

```
<div id='xyz' style="width:100%;height:70%;">
  something code
</div>
<button onclick="reduce()">Reduce</button>
<script>
  function reduce() {
    var xyz = document.getElementById("xyz");
    xyz.style.height = xyz.style.height-1%;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Why do you have `.value` in `document.getElementById.value("xyz").style.height` ?

Comment: sorry my mistake edited it

Comment: Try `document.getElementById("xyz").style.height=parseFloat(document.getElementById("xyz").style.height)-1+'%';`

Comment: is there any way to convert height in % into pixels ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to get the height, remove the `%` and convert to an int before deducting.

```html
<div id='xyz' style="width:100%;height:70%;">
  something code
</div>

<button onclick="reduce()">reduce</button>


<script>
  function reduce() {

    var height = document.getElementById("xyz").style.height; // 70%

    var heightInt = parseInt(height.substr(0, height.length - 1)); // 70

    document.getElementById("xyz").style.height = (heightInt - 1) + '%';

  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks that solved it but is there any way to convert height in % into pixels ?